# Upgrade yocto linux kernel fails

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I attempt to change the yocto build linux kernel version. I added the following modifications to my `local.conf`:

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-mainline"
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-mainline = "5.2%"
```

As expected it kicked off the recompilation of the kernel. However, when I `bitbake` the image it runs into the following error:

```
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides kernel-image-4.19.63 needed by packagegroup-core-boot-1.0-r17.tss_image
```

I had a look at the `packagegroup-core-boot.bb` defined in `poky/meta` but could not identify the root of the problem.

Any hints and comments are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a while ago since I asked this question but from the top of my head I think that I had to clean the sstate to fix this problem:

```
bitbake virtual/kernel -c cleansstate
```

Just in case other stumble across this post. Please correct me if I'm wrong.